# How to display a Japanese Characters in phpMyAdmin database?

Tags: php, html, database, cjk

on my database I've properly set up the Collation to `utf8_general_ci` in the case for the Japanese Characters may insert into the table. but when I tried to insert a Japanese character and viewing the table data in my phpMyAdmin database, It posted like this characters--> ãƒ™ãƒƒãƒ‰ãƒ¡ã‚¤ã‚¯(å®¢å®¤æ¸…æŽƒ)ã®ãŠä»•äº‹

How can I setup the phpMyAdmin to display the right Japanese characters?

on my HTML page I set up like this `<meta charset="utf-8">` 
em I wrong?

Comment: How are you viewing the database? In your Browser? Does the data show correctly in your web page?

Comment: Don't think Collation is something magical. It's just the algorithm used when sorting. Nothing else.

Comment: You enter the data through a PHP app and then try to view it in phpMyAdmin? Or you're entering it through phpMyAdmin and it displays incorrectly in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I know you are looking for a straight answer, but if you really are into online programming, this article is a must: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @Amit Gupta :) please scan this prob

Answer (score -3):

<strike>In doc of mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-cjk.html
Indicate that Japanese, Chinese and Corean have an own character set.</strike>

I hope that solved your problem.

Comment: Not that that's necessary. `utf8mb4` will do just fine and should be the preferred encoding anyway, unless you have some really specific reasons to use something else.